# I am writing Appium test for IOS in C# I have an assertion that requires me to use text as an assertion

Tags: c#, ios, appium, appium-ios

I am writing Appium tests for iOS in C#. I have an assertion that requires me to use text.

`"AddressCC"` is the correct accessibility Id for the field that gets populated and the text for the populated field is `"123 Main Street"`. I want to assert that the field is being populated with `"123 Main Street"`. The below comes back with Expected True But was False.

```cs
String actualString = (_IOSdriver.FindElementsByAccessibilityId("AddressCC")).ToString();

String expectedString = "123 Main Street";

Assert.IsTrue(actualString.Contains(expectedString));
```

Answer (score 0):

What does ".ToString()"?
should it be:

```
String actualString = (_IOSdriver.FindElementsByAccessibilityId("AddressCC")).Text;
```

Comment: I get a does not contain a definition for Text when attempting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the element text and store in the variable before the by using .getText() like below :

```html
String actualString = (_IOSdriver.FindElementsByAccessibilityId("AddressCC")).getText();
```

Comment: getText is a JavaScript thing does not work well with C#. Same Issue does not contain a definition for text.